# Ordering Varchar2 Table ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to order the Location_ID in correct numerical order. I have used a Varchar2 data type for Location_ID. I have created a SELECT statement that retrieves all diseases and its total number. At the moment the output looks like this. I want L20 to be the last result.

```
Location_ID    Name    Outlier_Value   Total
---------------------------------------------
L1            Disease      < 1         1
L2            Disease      < 1         1                 
L20           Disease      < 1         1
L3            Disease      < 1         1
L4            Disease      < 1         1
L5            Disease      < 1         1


SELECT Location_ID, Name, Outlier_Value, COUNT(*) AS 
Total 
FROM Measurement 
WHERE Outlier_Value IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Location_ID, Name, Outlier_Value
ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Comment: What's wrong with integer id's? If you had chosen that column data type you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Does the location_id always start with exactly one letter?

Comment: Do all `Location_ID`s start with `L` ?

Comment: Yes that is true but I have decided to use varchar2 for specific reasons @jarlh.

Comment: Yes they do start with L @Abra

Comment: @user9251416 then I would say that _Littlefoot_'s answer is a good one for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by to_number(regexp_substr(location_id, '\d+$'))
```

could be one option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your locations start with a single letter, then you can order by the length and then the value:

```
order by length(location_id), location_id
```

Comment: Thanks but could I ask how I could accomodate if I added a different letter at the start such as M1. L20 would end up at the bottom wouldn't it?

Comment: What happens if I changed L1 to LN1. How could I order it @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @user9251416 . . . If the prefix is the same size on all the rows.  Otherwise, you need to identify where the number begins.

Comment: (Just saying; if it is Oracle - as tagged - then `LEN` won't work, but `LENGTH` will).

Answer (score 0):

You could also format the string with a proper leftpad

```
order by lpad(location_id, 10,'0')
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this won't work ... at least, not with data set the OP presented in his message.